# const-pointer-to-type, pointer-to-const and terminology for const discussion

Tags: c++, terminology, constants, conventions

I believe I've come across part of the reason that so many people seem to be confused about `const` which is that the term "*const pointer*" which seems to be somewhat counterintuitive nomenclature in that when said(even by those who understand the subtleties) seems often intended to mean "*pointer-to-const*" or:

```
  const Type * foo;
```

However, when parsed without *a priori* knowledge of the convention (*e.g.* by newcomers),in  the term "*const pointer*" one might parse that "const" qualifies "pointer" and so expect it to mean "*const-pointer-to-type*" or:

```
  Type * const foo;
```

So my questions are:

1. Is "*const pointer*" accepted terminology for "`const Type *`" despite seemingly being a misnomer?
2. If it is, what is the conventional term for "*const-pointer-to-type*" or "`Type * const`" referred to in discussion?

Comment: I'd say that it is a pointer to const 'X'.
You'd also see this in the windows API, for example LPCSTR - Long pointer to a constant string.

Answer (score 3):

Yes- typically "const pointer" means pointer-to-const-object, not a-pointer-that-is-const, and it's probably because the first scenario is way more common, so it's understandable to assign to it the shorter form.

Normally for `const-pointer-to-type`, you would either just say that, or stick with the designator: `T* const`. It's very rare to discuss such pointers, so there is no particularly common expression for it as far as I know.

Comment: And so how to you normally refer to `Type * const` in discussion?

Comment: @Catskul: By spelling it out: "a pointer that is const." It's far less used, so the fact that it's cumbersome to say isn't a problem.

Comment: And the whole issue goes hand in hand with `const reference` and `reference to const` while it is not ambigue in C++ (a reference itself is always const) it just doesn't fit with nicely with English.

Comment: Since neither answer mentioned it: Because pointers are integeral, they're almost always passed by value, or const reference.  The same is usually applied to iterators, so there isn't really a reason for "Type * const"

Comment: @pmr, it's not an issue with the english language so much as it's an issue with the convention. Using the longer form would work just fine.

Comment: @Nicol, the issue that I'm bringing up is not cumbersomeness, but rather confusion about the meaning. Someone new to the discussion woul d very likely parse "const pointer" to mean that the pointer itself is const.

Comment: @Catskul: This is not a forum. You asked if "const pointer" widely means "pointer to a const object". It does. You asked what the term for a "pointer that is const" is. The answer was provided. Anything else (like whether this might cause confusion or whatever) is a discussion best handled on a forum. Which SO is not.

Comment: @Nicol, DeadMG's answer did not answer the second part of the question. Feel free to post the complete answer or edit DeadMG's to include the second half of the answer. The comment section is not the correct location for answers.

Comment: @Catskul: It is also definitely not appropriate to edit someone else's answer with your own.

Comment: @DeadMG, I was being a bit facetious there.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `const Type* foo` is usually called a const pointer.

The reason why this kind of constness has a name, is because this type of constness is more sticky than the other one. If you get a pointer-to-const object, you can not convert it to a non-const one. 
But if you get a pointer that itself is const, but points to a mutable object, you can alsways copy it to a writable field.

Lastly, pointer-to-const would suggest that the pointed object is const. It is not, it can change, you just have a read-only view of the object. In that sense, the constness applies more to the pointer than the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

const is a so called qualifier. It qualifies that comes next.

In the case of const type* var ,it means that the value of type is const ,so it's called a **const(ant) *type*** pointer.

In the case of type* const var ,it means that the value of var is const ,so it's called a ***type* pointer** const(ant).

Notice the subtle difference between the two.

Comment: "*It qualifies that comes next.*" IMO that's exactly what's wrong with the use of "const pointer" to mean "const type pointer". Using the same rule, one might think that in the term "const pointer" "const" qualifies "pointer" in the nomenclature, when in fact, it doesn.

Comment: @catskul: that's the subtlety. I personally don't find it confusing.

Comment: @catskul: when someone uses the term const pointer I automatically assume const-type-pointer. But when one means type-pointer-const then they should use the term pointer-const(ant)

Comment: I understand that there is a convention, and now, with your answer, what the convention is. I'm saying though that without first knowing the convention, the nomenclature can easily be mis-parsed.

Comment: @catskul: I do understand your point. But when your programming C/C++ for over twenty years (like I am) ,it's just second nature.

Comment: 'const' doesn't qualify 'what comes next', because 'const Type * ' is the same as 'Type const * ' - in this case the 'const' is before the '*'.  I personally prefer putting the const to the right of what it qualifies always as this is consistent - same goes for types, pointers, member functions.

Comment: @edwin, I made some edits to call out the answers (+ some formatting).  If you can accept the edits, I'd say it answers the questions and can be marked.

Comment: @pete: I knew that someone would come with this. And my personal opinion on this awfull usage cannot be expressed without offending someone ,so I won't. I only hope that the standard sometime will consider this a syntax-error. And you right ,in this case my statement is not accurate. \\

Comment: @catskul: your editted-question looks fine to me. And all the answers\comments given so far are all valid.

Comment: @Edwin, I think you(someone) have(has) to accept it. It tells me that it's only visible to me until reviewd.

Comment: @catskul: Never heard about such a thing. I thought that only the questioner can accept an answer. Anyhow ,it doesn't give me the option to accept any answer (thankfully). Just wait for it to be reviewed ,whatever that is.

Comment: @pete, +1 for consistency, but after does feel a bit odd none-the-less